# Rails 5 Div dynamic selectbox and remote div layout issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am building out an app in Rails 5, Ruby 2.4.0 and using Bootstrap 4 Alpha 6

I have a dynamic selectbox that when a selection is made loads a div below that displays information on that item, the problem is the layout of the div, When i click one selection it show properly, when i click the next selection, it appears below the first select item.

What i am tying to achieve is a single div that loads dynamically based on the initial device selection.

I am not sure how to proceed with this and am rather new with javaScript and AJAX.

> **my selecctbox:**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="deviceSelect">Select Your <%= @manufacturer.name.titleize %> Device</label>
  <select class="form-control div-toggle" data-target=".device-names">
    <option>Select Device</option>
    <% @devices.each do |device| %>
      <option value="<%= device.id %>" data-show=".<%= device.device_name %>"><%= device.device_name.titleize %></option>
    <% end %>
  </select>
</div>
```

> **my "dynamic div":**

```
<div class="device-names">
  <% @devices.each do |device_div| %>
    <div class="<%= device_div.device_name %> invisible">
      <%= device_div.device_name %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

> **my javaScript:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).on('change', '.div-toggle', function() {
        var target = $(this).data('target');
        var show = $("option:selected", this).data('show');
        $(target).children().addClass('invisible');
        $(show).removeClass('invisible');
      });
      $(d

ocument).ready(function() {
    $('.div-toggle').trigger('change');
  });
</script>
```

I would like the content for each device to load where the Iconica text is located in the image below, at least thats my end-game. 
[image: Iconica Selected and shows where the div text for all devices should be]
[image: Shows where second item is appearing, should not be where it appears.]

Any assistance here would be GREATLY appreciated! Thanks in advance, Please ask for further info if it has been negated here.

Answer (score 0):

so the issue was the bootstrap invisible class, I modified the bootstrap class to include display: none; in my css and it produced the desired result.